# How can I Concat two strings in F#?

Tags: f#

I have two strings :

```
let input=Console.ReadLine()
let check=""
```

i am looking for a function that can concat this two strings. What should I do ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings#string-operators

Comment: you have to accept answer if it fit you

Comment: You do realize that concatenating the empty string is rather like adding zero, or multiplying by one, don't you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `+` operator:

```
let both = input + check
```